# Clojure: calling a sequence of methods on a Java object

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have seen this somewhere documented but I cannot remember where and what was the name of the function: what I am searching for is a function/macro that takes (a Java) object as an argument, executes a sequence of methods on that object and returns it. Something like that:

```
(<the function> obj
  (.setName obj "the name")
  (.setAmount obj42.0)
  ; ...
  (.setDescription obj "the description"))  ; returns the updated obj
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `..`:

```
(.. obj (setName "the name") (setAmount 42.0) ... (setDescription "the description"))
```

If the methods do not return the target object you can use `doto`:

```
(doto obj (.setName "the name") (.setAmount 42.0) ... (.setDescription "the description"))
```